# Why does traceroute time out when I try it on certain hosts?

Tags: networking, centos, routing, traceroute

I have a large LAN set up with over 100 hosts.

Most of the time traceroute works fine, but in certain cases between two particular hosts, it times out.

I have tried the default traceroute as well as using ICMP and TCP traceroute with the -I and -T flags.

I have disabled the firewall on every single host on the network.

I have tried to do a "manual" traceroute by sending pings and incrementing the ttl flag until the destination is reached and it works fine.

Ive ran out of ideas on what could be the issue.

Comment: Could you add some info about the network structure, such as number of routers the request passes through and is there more than one possible path, network throughput and usage, operating systems etc. Does ping always work? Is the problem only between two specific computers?

Comment: I cannot provide too much info on the network topology due to security concerns.  There are typically between 2-6 hops between problem hosts.  There is only one path from each host to any other host according to the routing table. Useage is negligible. OS is CentOS 7, ping always works. Yes the problem is between specific hosts. I should note these hosts are not on the same subnet

Comment: At least answer the above questions. Network schema is not required.

Comment: Sorry, i didnt know pressing enter would send comment, ive edited my response.

Comment: Does it always fail between these two hosts? Are there more than one such pair, and if yes is there a common factor such as same router or network segment?

Comment: Yes it always fails, and there are several such pairs. I cant discern any pattern between problem hosts other than the fact that they are never on the same subnet.

Comment: If you took one computer from one pair that always fails and put it in another network segment, will this still fail?

Comment: I dont have the capability to do what you described. But  some hosts on the same subnet as the problem hosts can successfully traceroute